# make + tex: file not found

Tags: makefile, tex

I have a directory with the following files

```
➜  hrrep git:(master) ✗ ls -l
total 1000
drwxrwxrwx  22 zmjones  staff    748 May 28 23:28 data
-rw-rw-rw-   1 zmjones  staff   7180 May 20 16:17 data.R
drwxrwxrwx   9 zmjones  staff    306 May 28 23:38 figures
-rw-r--r--   1 zmjones  staff  85841 May 28 23:23 hill_jones_hr.bib
-rw-r--r--   1 zmjones  staff  29193 May 28 22:23 hill_jones_hr.tex
-rw-r--r--   1 zmjones  staff    572 May 28 23:46 makefile
-rw-rw-rw-   1 zmjones  staff   9588 May 28 22:47 models.R
drwxrwxrwx   3 zmjones  staff    102 May 28 23:28 papers
drwxrwxrwx   9 zmjones  staff    306 May 28 23:28 tex
-rw-r--r--   1 zmjones  staff   1483 May 20 12:58 un_data.py
```

These files are described by a makefile (using GNU Make 3.81)

```
all: ./data/cat_un_data.csv ./data/rep.csv ./figures/*.png ./hj-hr.pdf

./data/cat_un_data.csv: un_data.py #refreshing one will refresh all
        python un_data.py

./data/rep.csv: data.R ./data/cat_un_data.csv
        R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore data.R

./figures/*.png: models.R ./data/rep.csv
        R CMD BATCH --no-save --no-restore models.R

TEXMCD := pdflatex -interaction=batchmode

hill_jones_hr.pdf: hill_jones_hr.tex ./figures/*.png
    $(TEXCMD) $<
    ]bibtex *.aux
    $(TEXCMD) $<
    $(TEXCMD) $<
    find . | egrep ".*((\.(aux|log|blg|bbl|out|Rout|Rhistory|DS_Store))|~)$$" | xargs rm
    rm -rf auto
```

The makefile seems to work fine until it gets to the hll_jones_hr.pdf target, where it fails with an error:

```
hill_jones_hr.tex
make: hill_jones_hr.tex: No such file or directory
make: *** [hill_jones_hr.pdf] Error 1
```

I don't understand what the problem is. The document compiles fine when I execute `pdflatex` and `bibtex` manually. I tried adding the ignore error flag to no avail. I presume this is some stupid make error that I am making. This folder is in Dropbox if that makes any difference. I also tried adding the `./` prefix to both the `.tex` file and the `.pdf` target; the error was the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `$(TEXCMD)` variable is not defined, so your command:

```
$(TEXCMD) $<
```

is expanding to just `$<` or just the filename, which is not a legal command by itself.

Comment: I was just mis-spelling it. facepalm. I don't understand how I was supposed to go from the error "file not found" to TEXCMD is undefined. I see how it works now though. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, make will print the command that it executes.  If that's not the command you expected it to execute, as in this case where the `latex` or whatever command is not there, you need to look at the makefile rule and figure out what's wrong.  There's also the `--warn-undefined-variables` option to GNU `make`, however note this may give you a lot of false positives if you rely on make's promise that undefined values are empty.

Answer (score 0):

use `./hill_jones_hr.tex` instead of `hill_jones_hr.tex`, and try again.

Comment: No that didn't work. I also tried adding `./` to the pdf target, to no avail.